# How to display message through ViewBag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, viewbag

I need to display success msg when user registered. below i attached code. that code not displaying success msg. whats wrong. please help. (This is Asp.net core MVC web application)

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(UserAccount user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.UserAccounts.Add(user);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            ModelState.Clear();
            ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Registration Done";

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: You need to include the view. Otherwise, it's impossible for anyone to know what's going on.

Comment: @Andrew 'view' mean? output of this code? or full codes this page?

Comment: The view that should display your message, of course. The one that you are returning with `return View()`. Where are you inserting the contents of `ViewBag.Message`? If you are working with MVC, you should know what a "view" is. ;)

Comment: Try to read official documentation before using ViewBag. Link => [mvc](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: @ArzuSuleymanov, you linked the Czech translation, and by the way, that page doesn't mention ViewBag. You probably meant to link [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: @Andrew I mentioned just reading general information about MVC. As well as after reading going to ViewBag section.

Answer (score 5):

Anywhere in your HTML page you can use the viewbag.

Example:

```
<h4>@ViewBag.Message</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `ViewBag` at all for this. Use `TempData` instead and follow the PRG (post-redirect-get) pattern.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(UserAccount user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.UserAccounts.Add(user);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        TempData["Message"] = "Successfully Registration Done";
        return RedirectToAction("Foo");
    }

    return View();
}
```

On success, you need to redirect the user somewhere else. It makes no sense to return them to the registration form, after they've already registered, and it solves the issue of having to clear the model state. You use `TempData` to store the message, so it persists through the next request. Then, in your view:

```
@TempData["Message"]
```

Where you want it to display.